# Best datatype to store a long number made of 0 and 1

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

I want to know what's the best datatype to store these:

- `null`
- `0`
- `/* the length of other numbers is always 7 digits */`
- `0000000`
- `0000001`
- `0000010`
- `0000011`
- `/* and so on */`
- `1111111`

I have tested, `INT` works as well. But there is a better *datatype*. Because all my numbers are made of `0` or `1` digits. Is there any better datatype?

Comment: What about binary? e.g. int field? Make an int field nullable and store as binary (instead of the actual number you have) and you are sorted... unless you really need it as a string of course. You can use a very small data type since it looks like you only need 7 bytes

Comment: @Charleh What do you mean *"as string"*? I want to use it by a *Trigger* like this `IF ( SUBSTR(col, 1, 1) = 1) THEN ...` and `col` contains that binary number.  Also may you please write an answer?

Comment: What do you mean by 'better datatype'? You need to specify what you are trying to achieve for anyone to come up with a better datatype.

Comment: @stack if you are storing 010001 in an INT you will lose the leading 0 because 010001 is the equivalent of 10001 (unless you were storing as if it was a binary value). If you want to do `SUBSTR()` on this value it needs to be stored as a string. Alternatively you can store as a byte/numeric and use bitmasking to retrieve the 0/1 at certain bit positions. It's simple binary: `0 = 0`, `10 = 2`, `010001 = 17`. You then just use a bitmask check to see if any particular bit was set... e.g. `IF 8 & bitfield = 8 THEN ...`. Check out the link in Gary's answer.

Comment: @Charleh Ok, based on your explanations I want to store it as string. Because I need this `01 ≠ 1`. Please write a answer.

Comment: It is quite rare to use such lists of flags in a database. Anyway, as you want to use `substr(col, n, 1)` '10' is the same as '100000', correct? (You could just as well switch this to right-to-left, which would feel more natural and would allow for leading zeros.)  As has been mentioned, if you really want to store data thus in a database (which would be something very special and you should have very good reasons for not using a table instead), you shouldn't use a string, but a number where you look at the bits. (And these should be read from right to left.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you for your explanations. But no, `10` isn't the same as `1000000`. I have updated my question. May you please take a look it?

Comment: Okay, so now we are back to binaries. 7 "bits" read from right to left, just as we do with our decimal numbers. And 01 *does* equal 1, only you pad it with leading zeros (or even store it such) as to be able to access the "bits" via `substr(col, n, 1)`. One could use an integer datatype to store it, because an integer internally consists of bits of course. And as mentioned: You should have a good reason not to use separate columns or tables instead of an encoded column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are showing are binary numbers

- 0000000 = 0
- 0000001 = 2^0 = 1
- 0000010 = 2^1 = 2
- 0000011 = 2^0 + 2^1 = 3

So simply store these numbers in an integer data type (which is internally stored with bits as shown of course). You could use BIGINT for this, as recommended in the docs for bitwise operations (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html).

Here is how to set flag n:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET bitmask = POW(2, n-1)
WHERE id = 12345;
```

Here is how to add a flag:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET bitmask = bitmask | POW(2, n-1)
WHERE id = 12345;
```

Here is how to check a flag:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE bitmask & POW(2, n-1)
```

But as mentioned in the comments: In a relational database you usually use columns and tables to show attributes and relations rather than an encoded flag list.

Comment: `TINYINT UNSIGNED` can hold 8 bits; `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` can hold 16 bits, etc.

Comment: Don't use `POW(n-1)`, instead do `1 << n`

Comment: Not sure how this is the accepted answer when `01` and `1` are not supposed to be equivalent... Not your fault but just confused...!

Comment: @Charleh: It was the OP who was confused. Being so fixated on using `substr(col, n, 1)`, '01' and '1' could not mean the same. It took us all some time to enquire further to get the whole picture till the request was suddenly altered such that all strings were seven digits long. (And I still hope my answer was actually accepted, because I am recommending to rethink the whole thing in my last sentence :-)

Comment: That makes more sense thanks for commenting, oftentimes the question "what are you trying to do" is better than trying to answer an original question :)

Answer (score 2):

As you've said in a comment, the values `01` and `1` should not be treated as equivalent (which rules out binary where they would be), so you could just store as a string.

It actually might be more efficient than storing as a byte + offset since that would take up 9 characters, whereas you need a maximum of 7 characters

Simply store as a `varchar(7)` or whatever the equivalent is in MySql. No need to be clever about it, especially since you are interested in extracting positional values.

Don't forget to bear in mind that this takes up a lot more storage than storing as a `bit(7)`, since you are essentially storing 7 bytes (or whatever the storage unit is for each level of precision in a varchar), not 7 bits.

If that's not an issue then no need to over-engineer it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the best datatype, but you may want to try BIT:
[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-bit.html)

There are also some useful bit functions in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html).

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned in the comments, I have to use `SUBSTR()` function for that number. Still are you believe I have to use BIT?

Comment: You can't use this method as you've stated that `01` and `1` should not be treated as equal, when in binary they are equal.

Comment: You can maintain another `int` field to store the length, but I think string will be a better option for your usage, your code will be much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the binary number to a string, with an additional byte to specify the number of leading zeros.

Example - the representation of `010`:

- The numeric value in hex is `0x02`.
- There is one leading zero, so the first byte is `0x01`.
- The result string is `0x01,0x02`.

With the same method, `1010010` should be represented as `0x00,0x52`.

Seems to me pretty efficient.

Comment: How can I do that converting in MySQL ?

Comment: Do the conversion in your server, and then store the result in sql