# Efficiency of tables that have a mapping to another table where their real value is held in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am developing a small survey system that consists on inserting all the form data at once (around 90 questions will be answered). Also, you can consult the data later . Having this in mind, I wanted to ask what were the advantages of using a schema like such:

I have several questions in the survey that will have multiple checkboxes (some have 15+), and people will be able to select MULTIPLE of those checkboxes as their answer, and I will store all their selected options in the DB. I am achieving this by using the same name attribute in all those checkbox inputs (belonging to a question) as such: `name="q_01[]"`. The "problem" here (not really a problem, more like a performance/storage optimization enhancing) is that I don't want to store the same values over and over. Say, if I had 20 checkboxes, and their values (attribute in HTML `value="Real Value"`) were something long like Strawberry, Something, etc.. etc.., I would be duplicating the same value over and over, leading to space being wasted.

Instead, I want to store an integer, that will map to a table that holds the real value. That way, I would only store 4 bytes, instead of (UP TO) 255 chars as VARCHAR.

I have heard of such systems, but I have not done it myself, and I don't know any namings or conventions. Could you guys point me in the right direction (by posting an example/youtube vid or a page where there is one)? How are these tables called? I know the basics of foreign keys, and relational tables, so I know the answer lays somewhere in there.

Also, if you could include or give me a hint of how I could query such tables, that would be awesome!

Thank you for your help in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a question has 15 possible answers which can be chosen independently of each other, then each possible answer will become one table column of your answer table, having column names like `strawberry`, `raspberry`, etc. The name of the column doesn't have to be represented in the database itself (although it will be present in the information schema columns table https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html belonging to MySQL that, if for advance use cases, you can read from your software). Your columns for taking the checkbox values will all be `boolean` or `tinyint(1)`; these values should neither contain the string `strawberry` nor some foreign key to a record containing `strawberry`.

Answer (score 0):

See the `SET` datatype.

See `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`, it has 16 bits, each of which could indicate one answer.

More on the latter case:  [Best datatype to store a long number made of 0 and 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067982/best-datatype-to-store-a-long-number-made-of-0-and-1)